Pink ice cream on London Bridge
Several decades ago, IIRC on an episode of the UK children's TV show Rainbow, I heard the following version of "London Bridge is Falling Down":

London Bridge is falling down
Falling down, falling down
London Bridge is falling down
My fair lady.
We'll build it up with pink ice cream
Pink ice cream, pink ice cream
We'll build it up with pink ice cream
My fair lady.
The pink ice cream will melt away
Melt away, melt away
The pink ice cream will melt away
My fair lady.

The first lines of the subsequent verses were:

We'll build it up with bricks and stones
Bricks and stones we haven't got
We'll build it up with iron rods (or "bars"?)

AFAIR that's as far as the rendition went.
In the subsequent decades, I've come across variants of these subsequent verses, e.g., "bricks and mortar" that "will not stay", rather than "bricks and stones" that "we haven't got"; or "iron and steel" that will "bend and bow". I've also heard additional verses: "wood and clay" that will "wash away"; "needles and pins" that will "rust and break"; and "silver and gold" that will "be stolen away" unless protected by a watchman who smokes a pipe all night. However, I have never come across the verses about pink ice cream anywhere else. Were these verses nonce creations for the Rainbow episode, or are they a traditional part of the nursery rhyme?

The song surely dates back to a time long before ice cream was commonly available!

Yes, but the tv show rainbow surely was written and broadcast decades after ice cream was available and might have been mentioned in versions of popular songs, especially the type of songs where it was common to insert your own lyrics.
